# Do I need to call [super init] or [super initWithCoder], etc for NSObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, nsobject, superclass

Typically when I subclass from a `UI` class I will call the superclass initializer of interest. However, I'm not sure of the implementation details of `NSObject`, and it seems like there's not much going on in terms of member vars, so I wonder: do I need to call `[super init]` if my subclass extends `NSObject`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, no. The [documentation for `-[NSObject init]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init) says that

> The `init` method defined in the `NSObject` class does no initialization; it simply returns `self`.

Because it is documented and there's probably already a bunch of code that relies on it, that fact is *highly* unlikely to change in future versions of Mac OS X.

**Edit:** [BoltClock's a Unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970884/5696) brings up a point that I would like to make more hyperbolic: the total time saved by not calling `-[NSObject init]` for everyone ever running your program is unlikely to ever exceed the debugging time that you'd incur if you ever change the superclass for your class to something other than `NSObject` and forget to add a call to `[super init]`.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init), it doesn't appear to do any initialization at all:

> The `init` method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns `self`.

I suppose it would be harmless not to call `[super init]`, but there's no reason not to follow conventions and, you know, call it in your subclass anyway. For example, your subclass may end up inheriting from another class in future, which may contain initialization logic in its own `-init` method that your subclass will then require.

Answer (score 1):

Just call through one of `super`'s designated initializers in your implementation because you should just do what is clear and correct.