# NSApplicationDelegate not working without Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm attempting to create a macOS application without a storyboard in Xcode 8 (stable) on macOS Sierra. However, my `AppDelegate` is not even being initiated. Here's the code I have:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("Init")
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("Finished launching")

        // Create a window
        window = NSWindow()

        // Add the view controller
        let viewController = ViewController()
        window.contentView?.addSubview(viewController.view)

        // Show the window
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

Neither `init` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)` is being called. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine to me... there's no reason it shouldn't get to init or applicationDidFinishLaunching...

Comment: Why don't you just deselect Use Storyboards when creating a new project?

Comment: @LeoDabus Because it still gives me an XIB file. What's odd is that if I remove the XIB/Storyboard file as the "Main Interface" but keep it in the project, the AppDelegate is still called. However, once I delete it, it won't get called.

Comment: The other thing is that clearly the compiler is finding that flag since when I delete the flag, it says it can't find an implicit entry/start point (which makes sense).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to do a few things here

1. Delete `NSMainStoryboardFile` key/value from the plist
2. Create a `NSApplication` subclass and assign it to the `Principal Class (NSPrincipalClass)` key.

[image: assign custom class to principal class]

The name must be fully qualified with your module name.

3. Manually instantiate your delegate in your NSApplication subclass and assign it to the `delegate` property.

Make sure you keep a strong reference to your delegate object. Ive just used a `let` here.

```
class GrookApplication: NSApplication {

    let strongDelegate = AppDelegate()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.delegate = strongDelegate
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

e.g a simple delegate.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("wassup")
        //conceptual proof of life init override
        //wait until applicationDidFinishLaunching , specially for UI
    }

    var window: NSWindow!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("yo! I'm alive")
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: .titled, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2018** Verified High Sierra

Do **NOT** try and do window or view controller initialisation inside `init` this leads to double app initialisation issues and crashing. The app has not finished launching at this stage. Wait until `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to fire any significant operations.

Comment: how do you keep a strong reference? I tried  this and all worked ok - the window was shown, but when i tried to set the `styleMask` of the window to `.titled` it gave me an exception saying `Assertion failure in -[X.XApplication init], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.82.104/AppKit.subproj/NSApplication.m:1778
2017-04-08 13:25:35.761585+0100 X[9073:1059806] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2017-04-08 13:25:35.761601+0100 X[9073:1059806] [General] Creating more than one Application`.

Comment: @TylerDurden the strong reference is done by using `var` or `let`. If you didnt do that the weak delegate reference releases the instance. i.e this `self.delegate = AppDelegate()` wont work. As to your other question without seeing your code i don't know. I suspect you tried to do this `[NSApplication sharedApplication].window` and its not working for reasons.

Comment: Keep in mind that this method not working on OS X Yosemite :)

Answer (score 23):

Warren Burton's accepted answer, utilising a strong reference to a `@NSApplicationMain`-annotated AppDelegate instance no longer works. I've confirmed it myself on OS X High Sierra, and Alex Sieroshtan commented that it didn't work back in OS X Yosemite, either. The failure point, as Tyler Durden noted, was this message:

```
Assertion failure in -[X.XApplication init], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.82.104/AppKit.subproj/NSApplication.m:1778
2017-04-08 13:25:35.761585+0100 X
[9073:1059806][General] An uncaught exception was raised 2017-04-08 13:25:35.761601+0100 X
[9073:1059806][General] Creating more than one Application
```

I struggled with this myself for a good while, but came up with two up-to-date solutions by *no small amount* of experimentation.

## Option 1: Continue to use `@NSApplicationMain` via a workaround

I found that you can alter the code of the accepted answer to work around the bug. The way to do this is by not calling the `super.init()` method in your class named `AppDelegate`.

### What?

Really. I think there is a too-eager assertion counting number of inits done by `AppDelegate` (or some logic along these lines), and thus the call to `super.init()` gets counted as well as the completion of the `override init()` block. You have two options for workarounds here:

1. **Don't call `super.init()`**: This is actually possible and [completely healthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970864/do-i-need-to-call-super-init-or-super-initwithcoder-etc-for-nsobject) for `NSObject`, at least in macOS. You lose the ability to reference `self` in the `override init()` block, however.
2. **Don't override `init()` at all**: Consider doing your init process during a lifecycle method like `applicationWillFinishLaunching(:)`.

I don't recommend either of these, of course.

## Option 2: Give up on the `@NSApplicationMain` method altogether

`@NSApplicationMain` is just a macro which we can approximate ourselves. By some luck, I came across James H Fisher's [blog post](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/11/13/how-is-appdelegate-instantiated.html) explaining how. I'll quote what matters in a moment.

*If you have written `@NSApplicationMain` anywhere, please delete it before proceeding with these instructions.*

### No need to alter your `Info.plist` file

The key:value pair for `NSPrincipalClass` should keep its default value of:

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>
```

### Use `main.swift` instead of subclassing `NSApplication`

The file MUST be called `main.swift`; it's a [special exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642372/expressions-are-not-allowed-at-the-top-level-if-the-module-is-not-main-swift) to Swift's "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" rule.

```
import AppKit

let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate

_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

### The logic

James H Fisher explains, referencing the `NSApplication` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsapplication):

> **[Docs]**
>
> Every app must have exactly one instance of `NSApplication` (or a subclass of `NSApplication`). Your program’s `main()` function should create this instance by invoking the `shared()` class method.
>
> **[James]**
>
> First, `main.swift` runs `NSApplication.shared`, and assigns this `NSApplication` object to `myApp`. Notice the documentation refers to a `main()` function, even though in Swift there is none! The equivalent is the `main.swift` file.
>
> Next, `main.swift` instantiates your `AppDelegate` class, and assigns it as the `.delegate` of `myApp`. You can now see why the default project chooses to call the class `AppDelegate`: it is set as the `.delegate` on an `NSApplication`.
>
> Finally, `main.swift` calls the function `NSApplicationMain(...)`... The function `NSApplicationMain(...)` is the entry point for Cocoa applications. `NSApplicationMain(...)` never returns; instead, it sets up the UI event loop, and eventually exits using the C `exit(...)` function.

Additionally [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382280/5951226) goes into some detail about why using `sharedApplication` remedies the "Creating more than one Application" bug.

... That's all you need! Hope this serves to help somebody else.

Comment: For further reading, see: "[What is the use of `@NSApplicationMain` in a Swift programming project in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469436/what-is-use-of-nsapplicationmain-in-swift-programming-project-in-xcode)".

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer with the salient point that UI shouldn't be init'ed in `init`  . The original implementation was conceptual to prove that the object is being instantiated by the app instance.

Comment: @WarrenBurton Thanks for determining that the UI is off-limits at init time in `NSApplicationMain`!

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is looking for a Swift version (based on @WarrenBurtons answer).

**AppDelegate**

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        window = NSWindow(contentViewController: RootViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
}

class RootViewController: NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
      self.view = NSView()
      self.view.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400)
  }
}
```

**NSApplication subclass**

```
import Cocoa

class Application: NSApplication {
    let strongDelegate = AppDelegate()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.delegate = strongDelegate
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Info.plist entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Application</string>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also created a gist for this, that I will keep up to date for new Xcode / Swift versions.
https://gist.github.com/florieger/7ac5e7155f6faf18666f92f7d82f6cbc

**Edit:** Make sure to delete the Main.storyboard / MainMenu.xib, otherwise you might end up with two Windows in the UI Debugger.