# How to Import the Objective c file in the swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge

Hello I am working on the react native project which i converted to swift from objective c using this [How to convert iOS react native template to swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167949/how-to-convert-ios-react-native-template-to-swift) thread.

Now I wanted to use this https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker to integrate this library i need to import orienation class but when i import the orientation class i am getting error

Here is the my project hierarchy

[image]

So my question is how we can import objective c files in swift project or how we can import the third party libraries in bridging header file

When i import it in this way

```
#import "Orientation/Orientation.h"
```

I am getting the following error

> ❌  error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/softech/Desktop/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.136.1/_work/r2/a/Application/ios/build/VidizmoMobileApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/VidizmoMobileApp-Bridging-Header-swift_G3EOBN6WTSYG-clang_3DYYERZEW34TU.pch' for bridging header /Users/softech/Desktop/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.136.1/_work/r2/a/Application/ios/VidizmoMobileApp-Bridging-Header.h
>
> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening VidizmoMobileApp.xcworkspace

Comment: @matt when i import this i am getting error Orienation.h not found

Comment: @matt I got it fixed i by adding the third party module path in the HeaderSearchPath as mentioned in the third step of this guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, 
as mentioned in the third step of this guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios

I also need to add the third party module in the HeaderSearchPath array as given in the picture

[image]