# How to convert iOS react native 0.68 template to swift?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, objective-c++

In `React Native` 0.68 for ios, the language being used is `objective-c++`, previously till 0.67 they were using `objective-c` which was easy for me to convert to swift thanks to [How to convert iOS react native template to swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167949/how-to-convert-ios-react-native-template-to-swift). Does anyone know how to convert objective C++ to swift in RN 0.68. I have some native modules in swift which is causing us not to upgrade to RN0.68

Below is my attempt to convert the code to swift

```
AppDelegate.swift


import Foundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  
  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application)
    //TODO set to yes to enable turbo modules
    RCTEnableTurboModule(true)
    
    let jsCodeLocation:URL
    jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index")
    
#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
    
    let rootView = RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView(
      bridge: bridge,
      moduleName: "DummyProject",
      initialProperties: [:]) as? UIView
#else
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "DummyProject", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    
    
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView
#endif
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
    } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    return true
  }
  
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    open url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
  ) -> Bool {
    return RCTLinkingManager.application(application, open: url, options: options)
  }
  
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
    restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void
  ) -> Bool {
    return RCTLinkingManager.application(
      application,
      continue: userActivity,
      restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
  }
}
```

Below is my Bridging header file

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
//Do add this app center dependencies which you removed to the original project
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>
#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <reacthermes/HermesExecutorFactory.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTJSIExecutorRuntimeInstaller.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <React/RCTDataRequestHandler.h>
#import <React/RCTHTTPRequestHandler.h>
#import <React/RCTFileRequestHandler.h>
#import <React/RCTNetworking.h>
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>
#import <React/RCTGIFImageDecoder.h>
#import <React/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTCxxBridgeDelegate, RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate> {
  RCTTurboModuleManager *_turboModuleManager;
  RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter *_bridgeAdapter;
  std::shared_ptr<const facebook::react::ReactNativeConfig> _reactNativeConfig;
  facebook::react::ContextContainer::Shared _contextContainer;
}
@end
#endif

//=============================

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED

#pragma mark - RCTCxxBridgeDelegate

- (std::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>)jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  if (RCTTurboModuleEnabled()) {
    _turboModuleManager =
        [[RCTTurboModuleManager alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                             delegate:self
                                            jsInvoker:bridge.jsCallInvoker];

    // Necessary to allow NativeModules to lookup TurboModules
    [bridge setRCTTurboModuleRegistry:_turboModuleManager];

    if (!RCTTurboModuleEagerInitEnabled()) {
      /**
       * Instantiating DevMenu has the side-effect of registering
       * shortcuts for CMD + d, CMD + i,  and CMD + n via RCTDevMenu.
       * Therefore, when TurboModules are enabled, we must manually create this
       * NativeModule.
       */
       [_turboModuleManager moduleForName:"DevMenu"];
    }
  }

  // Add this line...
  __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

  // If you want to use the `JSCExecutorFactory`, remember to add the `#import <React/JSCExecutorFactory.h>`
  // import statement on top.
  return std::make_unique<facebook::react::HermesExecutorFactory>(
    facebook::react::RCTJSIExecutorRuntimeInstaller([weakSelf, bridge](facebook::jsi::Runtime &runtime) {
      if (!bridge) {
        return;
      }

      // And add these lines to install the bindings...
      __typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
      if (strongSelf) {
        facebook::react::RuntimeExecutor syncRuntimeExecutor =
            [&](std::function<void(facebook::jsi::Runtime & runtime_)> &&callback) { callback(runtime); };
        [strongSelf->_turboModuleManager installJSBindingWithRuntimeExecutor:syncRuntimeExecutor];
      }
    }));
}

#pragma mark RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate

- (Class)getModuleClassFromName:(const char *)name
{
  return RCTCoreModulesClassProvider(name);
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                      jsInvoker:(std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::CallInvoker>)jsInvoker
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                     initParams:
                                                         (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (id<RCTTurboModule>)getModuleInstanceFromClass:(Class)moduleClass
{
  if (moduleClass == RCTImageLoader.class) {
    return [[moduleClass alloc] initWithRedirectDelegate:nil
        loadersProvider:^NSArray<id<RCTImageURLLoader>> *(RCTModuleRegistry * moduleRegistry) {
          return @ [[RCTLocalAssetImageLoader new]];
        }
        decodersProvider:^NSArray<id<RCTImageDataDecoder>> *(RCTModuleRegistry * moduleRegistry) {
          return @ [[RCTGIFImageDecoder new]];
        }];
  } else if (moduleClass == RCTNetworking.class) {
     return [[moduleClass alloc]
        initWithHandlersProvider:^NSArray<id<RCTURLRequestHandler>> *(
            RCTModuleRegistry *moduleRegistry) {
          return @[
            [RCTHTTPRequestHandler new],
            [RCTDataRequestHandler new],
            [RCTFileRequestHandler new],
          ];
        }];
  }
  // No custom initializer here.
  return [moduleClass new];
}

#endif
```

I am not sure where to add below code which is missing from my project after converting to swift

```
 _contextContainer = std::make_shared<facebook::react::ContextContainer const>();
   _reactNativeConfig = std::make_shared<facebook::react::EmptyReactNativeConfig const>();

   _contextContainer->insert("ReactNativeConfig", _reactNativeConfig);

   _bridgeAdapter = [[RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter alloc]
         initWithBridge:bridge
       contextContainer:_contextContainer];

   bridge.surfacePresenter = _bridgeAdapter.surfacePresenter;
```

I have enabled `RCTEnableTurboModule` in `AppDelegate.swift` file
I have enabled `Hermes` and `fabric` in pod file

```
:hermes_enabled => true,
:fabric_enabled => true,
```

I updated babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    './node_modules/react-native/packages/babel-plugin-codegen',
  ],
};
```

I did `npm install` and `USE_FABRIC=1 RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install`

I see a white screen on simulator when I run the app
When I try to run via Xcode , I again see the white screen with the msg saying `Unable to find module RedBox` in `Xcode` logs

Comment: Though this does not answer the question so I am putting this as a comment, the reason I was trying to convert Appdelegate to swift is because I had my own native modules in swift and I had converted my Appdelegate to swift for rn 0.67 and below versions. But for RN 0.68 you can keep app delegate in objc++ and have your native swift modules side by side. This is possible with previous version of RN as well. Its just that I was not aware of it.