# How to use an existing swift app in react native?

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

There are some things that CAN be done in react native but due to performance concerns, I have decided to implement in Swift and then run it in react native, for example, image processing.

Suppose I have a swift app that doesn't do anything other than displaying `Hello World` like so:

[image]

the code for it is not modified at all:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I would like to run this simple app in react native in this fashion:

```
SimpleApp.show();
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do so using [NativeModules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

Interesting helpful article that helped me through my fitness application: [Swift Modules for React Native](https://moduscreate.com/blog/swift-modules-for-react-native/)

And this one would help too!
[React Native app in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081012/react-native-app-purely-in-swift)