# Inject dependencies in xib controller

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swinject

I'm developing a macOS application that only consists of a menu bar icon.

I have a xib file (MenuBarMenu.xib) with the menu and a corresponding controller(MenuBarMenuController.swift) that puts it in menubar.

[image]

I want to inject dependencies in this controller, either manually or with Swinject.

So to do this I thought I could load the xib file programmatically from AppDelegate:

```swift
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let controller = MenuBarMenuController(nibName: "MenuBarMenu", bundle: nil)
        controller.someDependency = Test()
 }
```

But it looks like controller is being instantiated automatically by NSApplication before reaching applicationDidFinishLaunching.

What I've tried:

1. Removed NSMainNibFile from info.plist
2. Removed NSMainStoryboardFile from info.plist
3. Cleared Main Interface setting in project settings
4. Added LSUIElement = yes
5. Used [custom main.swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008141/nsapplicationdelegate-not-working-without-storyboard) to make sure my AppDelegate is called.

If xib file is there, it's called before AppDelegate. When I delete it, there are no runtime errors.

My question is: **how can I inject a dependency in this controller?**

Comment: Be sure the controller already loaded (viewDidLoad). If loaded, you can perform inject dependency. It seems to be you have created a controller, but not pushed to any controller.

Comment: Did you create the project from scratch?

Comment: No, I used a Cocoa App template.

Comment: Which one? Did you add MenuBarMenu.xib?

Comment: macOS -> Cocoa App -> Use storyboard, Use coredata, but I've heavily modified it since. I now have MenuBarMenu.xib that I've added and a storyboard which I use for windows. Storyboard is referenced in info.plist in any way.

Comment: There are two controllers: one created by `MenuBarMenuController(nibName: "MenuBarMenu", bundle: nil)` and the object in the xib.

Comment: Fair enough, but is there a way for me to inject any dependencies in the controller from xib? Or reorganize the xib/code so that I can make an injection in this scenario.

Comment: Did you add `let controller = MenuBarMenuController` to access the controller? Where do you instantiate `MenuBarMenuController`?

Comment: Well, I tried to instantiate one in AppDelegate, though I'm not sure if it actually does what I want it to do. And the actual MenuBarMenuController is instantiated by the framework when xib file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't figure out how to inject a dependency in my particular scenario, I was able to work around it by using a storyboard instead of a xib file.
Then with the help of SwinjectStoryboard I can make the injection.